# What's the very best way to sync two Macintoshes?

Tags: mac, synchronization

Let's say a laptop and desktop (Mac mini). I want to keep both in sync when on the same network. What's the very best way to automatically sync specific folders?

Thanks

Comment: Jeff, This is sysadmin related since I'm the admin of both systems, and synchronization is an administrative topic (you even have a tag for it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Old school: rsync (should be installed already)
- New school: [Dropbox](https://www.getdropbox.com/)

Comment: Dropbox doesn't mention much about security. Saying that the data is 256 AES encrypted when stored doesn't fill me with confidence, really. However, I really like the suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Windows Live Sync
Is for mac, is free and is GREAT!
[sync.live.com](http://sync.live.com)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll take a look. URL doesn't work though.

Comment: url works, i just checked

Comment: ah, windows live sync, encrypts data before sending on the internet

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Me is what apple would like you to use but you can also check Busysync, it works OK to sync ical. and Chronosync to sync files.

Comment: Not so much worried about iCal. I tried Chronosync in the past and was disappointed. Might need to take another look. Thanks.